# Графическая оболочка для Cuda-программы

Tags: gui, сеть, cuda

Добрый день! Есть cuda-программа, производящая расчеты и запись в файлы (очень громоздкая). Каким способом лучше реализовать графический интерфейс для передачи параметров, чтобы можно было создать удаленное взаимодействие (программа на расчетном сервере, а оболочка в другом месте)?

Comment: Масса вариантов. Я бы сделал сервер, на который по HTTP из софтины с гуем шлются данные, а софтина на сервере их из БД берет и обрабатывает. Можно и вовсем сделать HTML-страницу в качестве гуя.